# Disable the :hover effect when unchecking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, hover

How do i remove the "hover" or hide it when a checkbox is deselected. Right now when i deselect a checkbox the hover effect is still there making it look very weird (See picture). It looks like the checkbox is checked when infact the user has unchecked it but the hover effect still remains

[Hoover effect pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiNSg.png)

EDIT:

The hoover looks like this in the css

```
.myclass:hover + span { 
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
background-image: url(../img/image.svg);
background-size: cover;
background-color: #fff;
border: none;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
left: 93.2%;
top: 52px;
```

}

Comment: Without showing your code how do you expect us to help you find the problems?

Comment: @DavidThomas why would you need to see the code? I am simply asking if it is possible and if so which direction should i move at. Either way i added a css on how :hover looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the hover is being added via a class and then remove the hover class when the box is unchecked:

```
var $cb = $("input[type=checkbox]");
if(!$cb.attr("checked")){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeClass("hover");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer , this is what i did i just switched the class to a dummyclass without a hover effect and used a timeout to give it back

Comment: It wont let me i dont know why